# What is the optimal algorithm for generating an unbiased random integer within a range?

Tags: c++, c, random, uniform

In this StackOverflow question:

[Generating random integer from a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range)

the accepted answer suggests the following formula for generating a random integer in between given `min` and `max`, with `min` and `max` being included into the range:

```
output = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1))
```

But it also says that

> This is still *slightly* biased towards lower numbers ... It's also
>   possible to extend it so that it removes the bias.

But it doesn't explain why it's biased towards lower numbers or how to remove the bias. So, the question is: is this the most optimal approach to generation of a random integer within a (signed) range while not relying on anything fancy, just `rand()` function, and in case if it is optimal, how to remove the bias?

**EDIT:**

I've just tested the `while`-loop algorithm suggested by @Joey against floating-point extrapolation:

```
static const double s_invRandMax = 1.0/((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0);
return min + (int)(((double)(max + 1 - min))*rand()*s_invRandMax);
```

to see how much uniformly "balls" are "falling" into and are being distributed among a number of "buckets", one test for the floating-point extrapolation and another for the `while`-loop algorithm. But results turned out to be varying depending on the number of "balls" (and "buckets") so I couldn't easily pick a winner. The working code can be found at [this Ideone page](http://ideone.com/oPhqK). For example, with 10 buckets and 100 balls the maximum deviation from the ideal probability among buckets is less for the floating-point extrapolation than for the `while`-loop algorithm (0.04 and 0.05 respectively) but with 1000 balls, the maximum deviation of the `while`-loop algorithm is lesser (0.024 and 0.011), and with 10000 balls, the floating-point extrapolation is again doing better (0.0034 and 0.0053), and so on without much of consistency. Thinking of the possibility that none of the algorithms consistently produces uniform distribution better than that of the other algorithm, makes me lean towards the floating-point extrapolation since it appears to perform faster than the `while`-loop algorithm. So is it fine to choose the floating-point extrapolation algorithm or my testings/conclusions are not completely correct?

Comment: It is biased towards lower number, since rand() produces number within certain range (defined by `RAND_MAX`), and `RAND_MAX` is usually not divisible by the divisor, so all numbers from 0 to RAND_MAX % divisor - 1 will have higher chance of being chosen.

Comment: Lets say you had a random number generator that gives with equal chances 0, 1 or 2. If you apply a modulo 2 on it to get either 0 or 1, you can see that 0 has twice the odds of getting chosen. I guess that is what was implied by the statement you quoted.

Comment: http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx

Comment: The input is an integer and the output is an integer - converting to floating point during the conversion isn't going to change the fact that some numbers will be more likely than others, although it might change which numbers those will be.

Comment: @Desmond: See my reply [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641629/generating-a-uniform-distribution-of-integers-in-c/11645590#11645590)

Comment: I hate voting to close questions, but the original question which this one references has high-scoring answers that _do_ explain why a simple modulus introduces bias and give at least two ways of eliminating the bias.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random integer from a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: The previous question predates C++11, which now solves this problem.

Comment: @MSalters:  The other question has high-scoring answers that recommend appropriate C++11 library classes and functions as well pointers to their Boost predecessors.  In the long term, it's more useful to update answers to old questions than to start duplicate ones.

Comment: I didn't see the edit so sorry if this comment is over a year late. If you really want to test the distribution, replace the random number generator with a simple sequence generator from 0 to RAND_MAX and make the number of balls RAND_MAX+1 times the number of buckets. See http://ideone.com/SaagxZ for a modification of my original test. You really need to use a much larger number of balls to test with true random numbers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem occurs when the number of outputs from the random number generator (RAND_MAX+1) is not evenly divisible by the desired range (max-min+1). Since there will be a consistent mapping from a random number to an output, some outputs will be mapped to more random numbers than others. This is regardless of how the mapping is done - you can use modulo, division, conversion to floating point, whatever voodoo you can come up with, the basic problem remains.

The magnitude of the problem is very small, and undemanding applications can generally get away with ignoring it. The smaller the range and the larger RAND_MAX is, the less pronounced the effect will be.

I took your example program and tweaked it a bit. First I created a special version of `rand` that only has a range of 0-255, to better demonstrate the effect. I made a few tweaks to `rangeRandomAlg2`. Finally I changed the number of "balls" to 1000000 to improve the consistency. You can see the results here: http://ideone.com/4P4HY

Notice that the floating-point version produces two tightly grouped probabilities, near either 0.101 or 0.097, nothing in between. This is the bias in action.

I think calling this "Java's algorithm" is a bit misleading - I'm sure it's much older than Java.

```
int rangeRandomAlg2 (int min, int max)
{
    int n = max - min + 1;
    int remainder = RAND_MAX % n;
    int x;
    do
    {
        x = rand();
    } while (x >= RAND_MAX - remainder);
    return min + x % n;
}
```

Comment: Well, it was when reading Java's source that I came across their implementation (which I still find quite nice, despite a bit non-obvious). Of course, that's not what is written in any of the answers here, as the naïve check as you copied from my answer is much easier to understand.

Comment: I wonder if it should properly handle the case when `n` is greater than `RAND_MAX`, so far it's an infinity loop.

Comment: Hm, this doesn't ever not terminate (or takes a very long time), with all the possible PRNGs? I suppose the RNG would have to eventually return all values in [0, RAND_MAX] for this to always work.

Comment: @DesmondHume, no it doesn't handle the case where n is greater than RAND_MAX - how could you hope to get a uniform distribution when some of the values aren't possible? You could put a check in the code for that condition.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak, the worst case is when n is RAND_MAX/2+1 and half of the random numbers will be thrown away on average. Worst-case can be much worse of course, but it should drop back to the mean if run enough times. A RNG that didn't produce all possible values in its range would fail most definitions of random.

Comment: Worst-case `n` gives an average number of times around the loop of exactly 2, as it's the infinite sum of probabilities 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + ... However, that's the *average* number of times around the loop. The actual number of times around the loop is nondeterministic. You might actually go 50 times around the loop, but it's exceedingly rare.

Comment: @DesmondHume when I first answered this question I hadn't seen "Lost" yet.  Your user name is much more interesting now.

Comment: @MarkRansom, the number of possible outputs from `rand()` is equal to `RAND_MAX + 1`, i.e. `rand()` generates pseudo-random numbers in the range `0` to `RAND_MAX`, both inclusive. So, when `min == 0` and `max == RAND_MAX`, signed integer overflow occurs (on the systems in which `RAND_MAX == INT_MAX`), invoking undefined behaviour, even though the arguments `min == 0` and `max == RAND_MAX` are perfectly valid. On the systems in which `RAND_MAX < INT_MAX`, the function still goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: I think that using `size_t` values by type-casting and using `remainder = (RAND_MAX + 1) % n` and `while (x >= (RAND_MAX + 1) - remainder)` should take care of this edge case.

Comment: @KushagrJaiswal you're right, `max==INT_MAX` is going to be a problem, but see my response to Desmond Hume.  I don't see how it's possible to get into an infinite loop otherwise.  I'm most familiar with the Microsoft compiler where [`RAND_MAX` is infamously only 32767](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/rand-max?view=msvc-170) and it has never been a problem.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that you're doing a modulo operation. This would be no problem if `RAND_MAX` would be evenly divisible by your modulus, but usually that is not the case. As a very contrived example, assume `RAND_MAX` to be 11 and your modulus to be 3. You'll get the following possible random numbers and the following resulting remainders:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1
```

As you can see, 0 and 1 are slightly more probable than 2.

One option to solve this is rejection sampling: By disallowing the numbers 9 and 10 above you can cause the resulting distribution to be uniform again. The tricky part is figuring out how to do so efficiently. A very nice example (one that took me two days to understand *why* it works) can be found in Java's [`java.util.Random.nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method.

The reason why Java's algorithm is a little tricky is that they avoid slow operations like multiplication and division for the check. If you don't care too much you can also do it the naïve way:

```
int n = (int)(max - min + 1);
int remainder = RAND_MAX % n;
int x, output;
do {
  x = rand();
  output = x % n;
} while (x >= RAND_MAX - remainder);
return min + output;
```

**EDIT:** Corrected a fencepost error in above code, now it works as it should. I also created a little sample program (C#; taking a uniform PRNG for numbers between 0 and 15 and constructing a PRNG for numbers between 0 and 6 from it via various ways):

```
using System;

class Rand {
    static Random r = new Random();

    static int Rand16() {
        return r.Next(16);
    }

    static int Rand7Naive() {
        return Rand16() % 7;
    }

    static int Rand7Float() {
        return (int)(Rand16() / 16.0 * 7);
    }

    // corrected
    static int Rand7RejectionNaive() {
        int n = 7, remainder = 16 % n, x, output;
        do {
            x = Rand16();
            output = x % n;
        } while (x >= 16 - remainder);
        return output;
    }

    // adapted to fit the constraints of this example
    static int Rand7RejectionJava() {
        int n = 7, x, output;
        do {
            x = Rand16();
            output = x % n;
        } while (x - output + 6 > 15);
        return output;
    }

    static void Test(Func<int> rand, string name) {
        var buckets = new int[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) buckets[rand()]++;
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", i, buckets[i]);
    }

    static void Main() {
        Test(Rand7Naive, "Rand7Naive");
        Test(Rand7Float, "Rand7Float");
        Test(Rand7RejectionNaive, "Rand7RejectionNaive");
    }
}
```

The result is as follows (pasted into Excel and added conditional coloring of cells so that differences are more apparent):

[image]

Now that I fixed my mistake in above rejection sampling it works as it should (before it would bias 0). As you can see, the float method isn't perfect at all, it just distributes the biased numbers differently.

Comment: Do you think that an obvious floating-point-based approach aimed to map the RAND_MAX range to a custom range (almost) without branching would be less CPU efficient than multiple divisions (`%`) and branches implied by the `while` loop?

Comment: If you use `(double)rand() / RAND_MAX * n` instead you get the same problem, it's just that it's not the lower numbers that are more likely but that you distribute the bias somewhat over the whole range. You don't remove the bias at all using that method. You still have the problem of evenly fitting 10 input numbers into 3 output numbers, which isn't possible.

Comment: I do not understand the phrase `distribute the bias somewhat over the whole range` -- appears self-contradictory.  Also, ITYM `... evenly fitting *11* input numbers into 3 output numbers ...`

Comment: Instead of having the more biased numbers up front as with the modulus you might bias 0 and 2 for example. Or 1 and 2. It's a little unpredictable because it depends on how the floating point numbers look like and where they switch to another number. You still have the bias though. And yes, it's 11 numbers. Forgive me a small typo on a comment I can no longer edit. The point stays the same.

Comment: @Joey Please see the edit to my post regarding some tests I've run using [this code](http://ideone.com/MCmoH).

Comment: @Јοеу Great answer, thanks. I have been trying to wrap my head around `nextInt(n)` for two days now, up until I stumbled upon this thread and your answer. One comment regarding your benchmark; there really isn't much difference between the naïve and java implementation of the rejection algorithm, particularly no more/less division/multiplication operations. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @posdef: There isn't. It's just that Java's variant needs quite a bit of thinking to understand what it does, while the naïve version is more straightforward (and should be slightly slower, I guess).

Comment: @Јοеу but since there really isn't a significant difference between them, I am not sure why you'd expect it to be slower

Comment: @posdef: Just re-read; ok, in this case there's probably no difference at all. The original Java code used bit masks to achieve the comparison. Those probably got lost in the attempt to reduce the range to 7. My code uses an explicit modulus operation per call (which somehow got copied over into the port of the Java method, I should probably fix that) which isn't present in the original code. Since the loop in most cases runs only once the additional overhead per call can make a difference. But not much (I'd also guess the code is much older, when Java was much slower).

Comment: In `Rand7RejectionNaive`, what in Heaven's name is that `output` variable for? There is absolutely no need for it — and it's only slowing things down. All that needs to happen at the end is `return x % n;` — it doesn't need to compute anything `% n` inside the loop.

Answer (score 6):

It's easy to see why this algorithm produces a biased sample. Suppose your `rand()` function returns uniform integers from the set `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`. If I want to use this to generate a random bit `0` or `1`, I would say `rand() % 2`. The set `{0, 2, 4}` gives me `0`, and the set `{1, 3}` gives me `1` -- so clearly I sample `0` with 60% and `1` with 40% likelihood, not uniform at all!

To fix this you have to either make sure that your desired range divides the range of the random number generator, or otherwise *discard* the result whenever the random number generator returns a number that's larger than the largest possible multiple of the target range.

In the above example, the target range is 2, the largest multiple that fits into the random generation range is 4, so we discard any sample that is not in the set `{0, 1, 2, 3}` and roll again.

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest solution is `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(min, max)`.

Answer (score 3):

You have touched on two points involving a random integer algorithm: Is it *optimal*, and is it *unbiased*?

#### Optimal

There are many ways to define an "optimal" algorithm. Here we look at "optimal" algorithms in terms of the number of random bits it uses on average. In this sense, `rand` is a poor method to use for randomly generated numbers because, among [other problems with `rand()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad/52881465#52881465), it need not necessarily produce random bits (because `RAND_MAX` is not exactly specified). Instead, we will assume we have a "true" random generator that can produce unbiased and independent random bits.

In 1976, D. E. Knuth and A. C. Yao showed that any algorithm that produces random integers with a given probability, using only random bits, can be represented as a binary tree, where random bits indicate which way to traverse the tree and each leaf (endpoint) corresponds to an outcome. (Knuth and Yao, "The complexity of nonuniform random number generation", in *Algorithms and Complexity*, 1976.) They also gave bounds on the number of bits a given algorithm will need on average for this task. In this case, an *optimal* algorithm to generate integers in `[0, n)` uniformly, will need **at least `log2(n)` and at most `log2(n) + 2` bits on average**.

There are many examples of *optimal* algorithms in this sense. See the following answer of mine:

- [How to generate a random integer in the range [0,n] from a stream of random bits without wasting bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046918/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-in-the-range-0-n-from-a-stream-of-random-bits/62920514#62920514)

#### Unbiased

However, any *optimal* integer generator that is also *unbiased* will, in general, run forever in the worst case, as also shown by Knuth and Yao. Going back to the binary tree, each one of the `n` outcomes labels leaves in the binary tree so that each integer in [0, n) can occur with probability 1/n. But if 1/n has a non-terminating binary expansion (which will be the case if n is not a power of 2), this binary tree will necessarily either—

- Have an "infinite" depth, or
- include "rejection" leaves at the end of the tree,

And in either case, the algorithm won't run in constant time and will run forever in the worst case. (On the other hand, when `n` is a power of 2, the optimal binary tree will have a finite depth and no rejection nodes.)

And for general `n`, there is no way to "fix" this worst case time complexity without introducing bias. For instance, modulo reductions (including the `min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1))` in your question) are equivalent to a binary tree in which rejection leaves are replaced with labeled outcomes — but since there are more possible outcomes than rejection leaves, only some of the outcomes can take the place of the rejection leaves, introducing bias. The same kind of binary tree — and the same kind of bias — results if you stop rejecting after a set number of iterations. (However, this bias may be negligible depending on the application. There are also security aspects to random integer generation, which are too complicated to discuss in this answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, the problem of generating random integers on [a, b] can be reduced to the problem of generating random integers on [0, s). The state of the art for generating random integers on a bounded range from a uniform PRNG is represented by the following recent publication:

Daniel Lemire,"Fast Random Integer Generation in an Interval." *ACM Trans. Model. Comput. Simul.* 29, 1, Article 3 (January 2019) ([ArXiv draft](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10941))

Lemire shows that his algorithm provides unbiased results, and motivated by the growing popularity of very fast high-quality PRNGs such as Melissa O'Neill's [PCG generators](http://www.pcg-random.org/), shows how to the results can be computed fast, avoiding slow division operations almost all of the time.

An exemplary ISO-C implementation of his algorithm is shown in `randint()` below. Here I demonstrate it in conjunction with George Marsaglia's older [KISS64](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c/qFv18ql_WlU/IK8KGZZFJx4J) PRNG. For performance reasons, the required 64×64→128 bit unsigned multiplication is typically best implemented via machine-specific intrinsics or inline assembly that map directly to appropriate hardware instructions.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* PRNG state */
typedef struct Prng_T *Prng_T;
/* Returns uniformly distributed integers in [0, 2**64-1] */
uint64_t random64 (Prng_T);
/* Multiplies two 64-bit factors into a 128-bit product */
void umul64wide (uint64_t, uint64_t, uint64_t *, uint64_t *);

/* Generate in bias-free manner a random integer in [0, s) with Lemire's fast
   algorithm that uses integer division only rarely. s must be in [0, 2**64-1].

   Daniel Lemire, "Fast Random Integer Generation in an Interval," ACM Trans.
   Model. Comput. Simul. 29, 1, Article 3 (January 2019)
*/
uint64_t randint (Prng_T prng, uint64_t s) 
{
    uint64_t x, h, l, t;
    x = random64 (prng);
    umul64wide (x, s, &h, &l);
    if (l < s) {
        t = (0 - s) % s;
        while (l < t) {
            x = random64 (prng);
            umul64wide (x, s, &h, &l);
        }
    }
    return h;
}

#define X86_INLINE_ASM (0)

/* Multiply two 64-bit unsigned integers into a 128 bit unsined product. Return
   the least significant 64 bist of the product to the location pointed to by
   lo, and the most signfiicant 64 bits of the product to the location pointed
   to by hi.
*/
void umul64wide (uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t *hi, uint64_t *lo)
{
#if X86_INLINE_ASM
    uint64_t l, h;
    __asm__ (
        "movq  %2, %%rax;\n\t"  // rax = a
        "mulq  %3;\n\t"         // rdx:rax = a * b
        "movq  %%rax, %0;\n\t"  // l = (a * b)<31:0>
        "movq  %%rdx, %1;\n\t"  // h = (a * b)<63:32>
        : "=r"(l), "=r"(h)
        : "r"(a), "r"(b)
        : "%rax", "%rdx");
    *lo = l;
    *hi = h;
#else // X86_INLINE_ASM
    uint64_t a_lo = (uint64_t)(uint32_t)a;
    uint64_t a_hi = a >> 32;
    uint64_t b_lo = (uint64_t)(uint32_t)b;
    uint64_t b_hi = b >> 32;

    uint64_t p0 = a_lo * b_lo;
    uint64_t p1 = a_lo * b_hi;
    uint64_t p2 = a_hi * b_lo;
    uint64_t p3 = a_hi * b_hi;

    uint32_t cy = (uint32_t)(((p0 >> 32) + (uint32_t)p1 + (uint32_t)p2) >> 32);

    *lo = p0 + (p1 << 32) + (p2 << 32);
    *hi = p3 + (p1 >> 32) + (p2 >> 32) + cy;
#endif // X86_INLINE_ASM
}

/* George Marsaglia's KISS64 generator, posted to comp.lang.c on 28 Feb 2009
   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c/qFv18ql_WlU/IK8KGZZFJx4J
*/
struct Prng_T {
    uint64_t x, c, y, z, t;
};

struct Prng_T kiss64 = {1234567890987654321ULL, 123456123456123456ULL,
                        362436362436362436ULL, 1066149217761810ULL, 0ULL};

/* KISS64 state equations */
#define MWC64 (kiss64->t = (kiss64->x << 58) + kiss64->c,            \
               kiss64->c = (kiss64->x >> 6), kiss64->x += kiss64->t, \
               kiss64->c += (kiss64->x < kiss64->t), kiss64->x)
#define XSH64 (kiss64->y ^= (kiss64->y << 13), kiss64->y ^= (kiss64->y >> 17), \
               kiss64->y ^= (kiss64->y << 43))
#define CNG64 (kiss64->z = 6906969069ULL * kiss64->z + 1234567ULL)
#define KISS64 (MWC64 + XSH64 + CNG64)
uint64_t random64 (Prng_T kiss64)
{
    return KISS64;
}

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    Prng_T state = &kiss64;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        printf ("%llu\n", randint (state, 10));
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get a perfect generator assuming rand() function that you have is perfect, you need to apply the method explained bellow.

We will create a random number, r, from 0 to max-min=b-1, which is then easy to move to the range that you want, just take r+min

We will create a random number where b < RAND_MAX, but the procedure can be easily adopted to have a random number for any base

PROCEDURE:

1. Take a random number r in its original RAND_MAX size without any truncation
2. Display this number in base b
3. Take first m=floor(log_b(RAND_MAX)) digits of this number for m random numbers from 0 to b-1
4. Shift each by min (i.e. r+min) to get them into the range (min,max) as you wanted

Since log_b(RAND_MAX) is not necessarily an integer, the last digit in the representation is wasted.

The original approach of just using mod (%) is mistaken exactly by

```
(log_b(RAND_MAX) - floor(log_b(RAND_MAX)))/ceil(log_b(RAND_MAX))
```

which you might agree is not that much, but if you insist on being precise, that is the procedure.