# QStandardItem keep editing appearance after modification

Tags: qt

I have a QStandardItemModel with a column editable.

I use the slot `onTableItemChanged(QStandardItem *pItem)` and the problem is:
when the editing of the text is finished the item keeps the editing appearance (like a `QLineEdit`)

Comment: Did you press "Return" after editing?

Comment: Yes, I press "Enter" to validate the editing.

Comment: Hi, can you post some of your code to see what really happens please ? Also, your Qt version and OS.

Comment: We really need to see a single-file, self-contained example. For inspiration on how to write such, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24996945/1329652) or [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24953206/1329652) or [this repository with 200+ of them](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown).

Comment: The problem is resolved.