# Random integral numbers from uniform distribution

Tags: c++, random

I have to write a c++ program and have a problem only with the following part:

> [...] for that purpose, you will need two random integral numbers from
>   uniform distribution on the set {0,1,...,9} (those two numbers have to
>   be generated with equal probability) [...]

I don't know math as good as c++, also I'm not allowed to use c++11. I've written the following simple code, but I doubt if it's correct? :P

```
//...
srand(time(0));
int first_number = rand() % 10;
int second_number = rand() % 10;
//...
```

Comment: is this part of your homework?

Comment: This question may be useful (duplicate?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-an-entire-range

Answer (score 1):

Only call `srand` once per program, not every time you want a random number. Using the modulus trick for random numbers usually doesn't give an even distribution. So no, the solution is probably not correct.

Comment: Do you see two calls to srand? Maybe I should buy myself a new pair of better glasses.

Comment: @JanGąser I can't tell from your code fragment, but if that is in a function which you call more than once, it would be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you need it to be truly uniform, or just very close. Your solution is close but not perfect.

Suppose you're using Microsoft's C++, which has a [`RAND_MAX` of only 32767](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dfe3bzd.aspx). Your odds of getting a 0 through 7 are 3277/32768, while your odds of getting an 8 or 9 are only 3276/32768.

There are plenty of questions here on StackOverflow on how to obtain a perfect distribution, such as this one: [What is the optimal algorithm for generating an unbiased random integer within a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758809/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-generating-an-unbiased-random-integer-within-a)