# Accuracy of Random

Tags: .net, random

I am trying to run some test of convergence of random
The average of 0, 1, 2 is 1 so the long run I would expect value minus 1 to go to zero
It is not going to zero - even with Unit16.max
I am getting like off by 300

Am I not running a big enough sample? 
Or is random off?
Or is something wrong with my program?

```
// private static System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
// this was not better than Random

Random ran = new Random();
public void RollEm()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int[] sums = new int[3];
    int val;
    int minVal = 0;
    int maxVal = 0;
    for (UInt32 i = 0; i < Int16.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        val = ran.Next(3);
        //val = (int)RollDice(3) - 1;
        sums[val]++;
        sum += val;
        sum--;
        if (sum < minVal)
            minVal = sum;
        if (sum > maxVal)
            maxVal = sum;

        if(i % 100 == 0)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("i {0}  sum {1}  val {2}", i, sum, val);
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("sum {0}   min {1}  max {2}", sum, minVal, maxVal);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("sums {0}  {1}   {2}", sums[0], sums[1], sums[2]);
}
```

I agree with the comments and answers about average not sum should go to zero.  I am using this for poker bankroll analysis so sum is what mattered to me.

Comment: Random generates Int32 numbers. `Next(3)` maps that to a range of 0-3 [using double arithmetic](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,186). You can get that discrepancy simply due to rounding errors

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Next(3) is supposed to map to 0,1,2

Comment: Which it does by converting that Int32 to a double between 0..1 and multiplying by 3. That is guaranteed to generate scaling errors during division and multiplication *and* rounding errors when converting the doulbe back to an int. I put the link to the source in the previous comment

Comment: @Paparazzi: What they are saying is that because it's expanding a floating-point number to that range, you have some values that are biased over the others, since the number of possible floating-point values is not evenly divisible by three.  See, e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11758872/73070) for an explanation. So yes, it maps to [0, 3), but not uniformly so.

Comment: @RenéVogt Yes, I am geting a sum of the deviation from the expected value.  That is my intent.

Comment: @Joey Refer to the documentation.  Next(3) returns [0,1,2]

Comment: @Paparazzi ok, but that sum is not a value to indicate the accuracy of `Random`. The average is a better criteria and the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

Comment: The sum should grow like the square root of the number of samples.

Comment: @CodesInChaos What is you basis for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some tests with that:

```
Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(0, Int16.MaxValue).Average(i => r.Next(3) - 1));
```

Three consecutive calls gives this output:

```
-0,0075991088595233
0,00729392376476333
-0,00524918362987152
```

So you see the **average** is almost `0`.

But three consecutive calls to

```
Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(0, Int16.MaxValue).Sum(i => r.Next(3) - 1));
```

gives

```
38
133
146
```

This means that in `Int16.MaxValue` random numbers there have **only** been e.g. 133 more `+1` than `-1`. Thatswhy the average is not exactly `0` but a *little* off.

So the "mistake" in your code is that you are checking the **sum** instead of the **average**. You need to divide the `300` you are off by by `Int16.MaxValue`.

You probably thought that substracting 1 would lead to an average as `+1` and `-1` should cancel each other, but when you think about it: if you worked with the values *1 to 3*, your sum would *not* be 2 but a *really great value*.

Comment: I hear you but I would expect the sum to go to zero over a large number as I am subtracting the average each run sum--;.   Nice use of enumerable.

Comment: As your code reads now, you are subtracting 1 from sum in each iteration, so you effectivly substract `Int16.MaxValue` from your sum. In fact, the value you are off should increase with the number of iterations. If you have 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 iteration it would be very improbable that there are _exactly_ 1/3 `-1`, 1/3 `0` and 1/3 `+1`. The mistake would be much higher than only 300.

Comment: @Paparazzi 65K isn't a large number. I suggest you use one of the LINQ one-liners used in all these answers with the aggregate function you want (Count, average, stddev through Math.Net) and check with larger numbers - even 65M (ie 65K * 100) takes seconds. You'll see that the diference is small and constantly changing. The built-in Random algorithm isn't great but it's not that bad either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I let it go go Int32 and it was not much better.

Comment: @Paparazzi it won't get better, that's basic stochastics. Only the average should go to zero, but not your sum. As I said, I would even expect that sum to increase with more iterations.

Comment: @RenéVogt OK I am agreeing that avg is a better way of looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

No, Random is not off. It just means that over the whole 65536 numbers you summed, about 300 more were 2 than 0. That's actually not that many, compared to the total number of dice rolls you did there. The arithmetic mean of all the numbers you rolled is only *guaranteed* to hit 1, if you do infinite dice rolls. You already have an average of 1 accurate to two decimal places, which certainly is good enough here.