# Guaranteeing three digits in a randomly generated number

Tags: c++

I had an assignment that required us to generate a three digit number twice so a student can add them together and then check their work. I am still very, very new to C++ and my class regretfully provided no information on how to even do this. He provided no videos, articles, or anything on randomly generating numbers, how to secure a specific number of digits, or even how to add them together.

The following is the code I cobbled together, as crude as it is. I cannot guarantee three digits. Every now and then, it will be a two digit number. I have already emailed him to see if he can point me in a correct direction, but I am not optimistic. I was thinking there would be some way I could set a minimum value, but after hours of searching for this, I could not find an answer.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;  //This is so I do not have to type std::

int main(void)
{
    int set1; 
    int set2;
    int sum=0;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL)); // sets the random seed to provide different number utilizing the time of the computer

    set1 = rand() % 999 + 1; //creates a randomly generated three digit number
    set2 = rand() % 999 + 1; //created a randomly generated three digit number


    cout << "\n\n\n Are you ready for some math practice?\n\n\n";
    cout.width(8); //sets width of the columns to align everything
    cout << set1 << "\n"; //prints first generated set
    cout << " +   ";

    cout << set2 << "\n"; //[rints second generated set
    cout << "---------\n";
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    sum = set1 + set2; //add the two generated sets together
    cout << "Try to solve the problem. Have you got it?\n";
    system("Pause"); //waits for student to press enter to continue
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    cout << "The answer is: "; 
    cout << sum; //displays sum of two numbers
```

Comment: Why not just generate a random number between 0 and 899, then add 100 to it?

Comment: You're close: `rand() % 999` will generate a number between `0` and `998`. Instead, you should probably generate a number between `100` and `898` (`rand() % 899 + 100`) then add `100`. Someone will likely answer with better mish-mash than what I've written though.

Answer (score 4):

#### The usual C method

This is what you are using. You need three pieces of information:

- **minimum value**. For you it is 100. (The first three-digit number.)
- **maximum value**. For you it is 999. (The last three-digit number.)
- **range**, which is (maximum - minimum + 1). For you, that is (999 - 100 + 1) → 900.

To compute it the C-method way, compute the remainder of division by your range and add the minimum value. That is:

```
set1 = rand() % 900 + 100;
```

Any number modulo 900 gives you a value in 0..899. Add 100 and you get a number in 100..999. Voilà!

#### The *correct* C method

The above method suffers from bias (thanks to the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)). The way to fix it is to simply pull random numbers until you get one in the desired range:

```
int random_in_range( int minimum, int maximum )
{
  int result;
  do result = rand();
  while (result < minimum || maximum < result);
  return result;
}
```

Now you can simply ask for the number you want:

```
set1 = random_in_range( 100, 999 );
```

The only caveat is very small ranges (like 0..3) may produce noticeable lag; you will want to be a little more sophisticated about that. (Such as ask for numbers in 0..399 and divide by 100.)

#### The C++ method

Since you are using C++, you might as well learn how to do it properly.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

int random_in_range( int minimum, int maximum )
{
  thread_local std::ranlux48 rng( 
    std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() );
  return std::uniform_int_distribution <int> ( minimum, maximum )( rng );
}

...

set1 = random_in_range( 100, 999 );
```

Here we use a static (thread-safe — if you only have one thread just use the word `static` instead of `thread_local`) pseudo-random number generator, and we get a number from it using a uniform integer distribution in the range given by the minimum and maximum value desired.

It is all wrapped up in a convenient function so it looks the same when using it as in the C version, but it is much nicer in terms of:

- bias
- speed
- quality

#### In all cases...

you can use your existing code in the same way: Generate two random three-digit numbers, ask the user to input their sum and compare his answer to yours.

Comment: About the *correct* C method, you can use something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11766794/4944425

Answer (score 2):

You're very close!

```
set1 = rand() % 999 + 1; //creates a randomly generated three digit number
```

This actually generates a random number between `1` and `999`. What you want instead is to generate a number between `100` and `999`, and the easiest way to do that is to generate a number between `0` and `899` then add `100`:

```
set1 = rand() % 900 + 100; //creates a randomly generated three digit number
```

`rand()` is fine for your purposes, but you can make this even clearer and get better results by using [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(100, 999); // our distribution is between 100 and 999
    // print 100 random numbers to test
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++ i)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << "\n";
}
```