# DIfference in output of srand() on windows gcc and expected output for C programming?

Tags: c, gcc, random

i would like to know why there is a difference in the output from my gcc compiler in Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10 and the expected output? If so how can i change the compiler such that it operates the same?

This is the expected output, which i can receive when utilising https://repl.it/repls/InternalSeveralEntropy with **gcc 4.6.3**

```
The set of numbers are:

1 4 3 3 7 2 3 2 9 9 10 9 5 2 10 7 2 3 1 1
```

However, this is the output i receive using multiple gcc versions, **5.4.0**, **6.3.0**, **8.1.0** and even **4.6.3**.

```
The set of numbers are:
2 2 8 6 8 2 3 8 4 6 10 5 9 2 8 10 7 2 1 6
```

I have tried searching and the closest i have come to understand is that it has soemthing to do with srand() functioning differently? Attached below is my code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void) {

    int N = 20, DATA[20];

    int i; //< you local variables here >

    srand(454646); //don't change this line! Will be used in autograding... You may fail test cases if change this

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){        //< generate rand numbers and store here in DATA array >
        DATA[i] = rand()%10 + 1;
    }

    printf("The set of numbers are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("%d ", DATA[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //< write using FOR loops to determine MODE and print >

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Irrelevant: You need to seed `srand` for generating decent randomness.

Comment: Hmm...maybe they should generate the same sequence. Using VC2008 it generated the correct sequence.

Comment: I believe `replit` uses Linux, and thus perhaps may use a different implementation for `rand` than that of ming-gw's gcc running on Windows. I wouldn't focus on the differences of your randomness with theirs.

Comment: @WedaPashi Please note that it may be useful in some contexts (like testing) to produce the same pseudo random sequence every time.

Comment: @Bob__: Ah, I didn't realise it. Thanks!

Comment: The source code for `rand()` is here: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=stdlib

Comment: *//don't change this line! Will be used in autograding... You may fail test cases if change this*  Wow.  Does whoever created this problem know that the data from `rand()` is implementation-dependent?  If so, did that person specify the exact implemention (compiler, OS, C runtime library, etc) that you have to use?  If not, that person doesn't understand the problem.

Answer (score 6):

From C11 standard:

> 7.22.2.1 The rand function
>
> ...
> Footnote: There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced and some implementations are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits. Applications with particular requirements should use a generator that is known to be sufficient for their needs.

This quote makes clear that `rand` and `srand` are implementation defined, and the sequence of the program (used for grading!) is also implementation defined.

Answer (score 4):

As part `7.22.2.1` of C11 standard mentions, output of `rand()` function is implementation defined, so it may change based on each implementation (or even versions of compiler).

The only thing that is guaranteed is this:

> Returns a pseudo-random integer value between ​0​ and RAND_MAX (0 and
>   RAND_MAX included).

This means that even uniform distribution is not guaranteed too.

If you need a generate pseudo-random numbers generator which is guaranteed to create same sequence all the time (for each seed), you need to write that functions yourself. One way to write such a function is using [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register), or you can check implementation of a `rand()` function for a specific version and add it to your code as a your application specific random function like `myrand()`.