# Problem picking a random number within a range set

Tags: c++, random

I have this code:

```cpp
cin >> command;
if (command[0] == 'R' or command[0] == 'r') {
    if (command[1] == 'o' and command[3] == 'l' and command[2] == 'l') {
        if (command[4] == '\0') {
            cout << rand()+ 1 << endl;
        } 
        else if (command[5] == '\0')
        {
            NumberName = command[4];
            cout << (rand()%NumberName)+ 1 << endl;
        }
        else if (command[6] == '\0')
        {
            NumberName = command[4] + command[5];
            cout << (rand()%(NumberName))+ 1 << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Running it produces random numbers outside of the range.

`command` is an array with a limit of 30.

`NumberName` is just a normal `int`.

I enter `roll10` in the console and it returns `90` then `34` then `51`, you get the idea.

Comment: what is the range do you want?

Comment: i probably should have included this but earlier in the script it asks the user for a input using cin >> command;

Comment: `rand` is a pretty bad way of getting random numbers. I suggest using [uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution); it's way more user-friendly and yields better numbers. If you are interested in why, see this question [why is the use of rand considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad/52881465)

Comment: yes it is a char array but i dont really know how else to decompile the input

Comment: You need to parse the string, ideally, you should put a separator between roll and 36, e.g. `roll:36` then you can split the string on the `:` and treat the left as a command and the right as a number, which you can convert with `atoi`.

Comment: thanks! im gonna try to find out how to actually split the string now

Comment: @nick no need for `atoi()`, just put the `command` into a `std::istringstream` and then use `std::getline(':')` to extract `roll` and `operator>>` to extract `36` directly into the `int`

Answer (score 0):

Please [do not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52869166/430766) use `rand()` and in particular [do not](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb-1grkVGSg) use `%` to shrink to a range because this produces a non-uniform distribution.

The C++ standard library specifically has a [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) type for this. Use this with [mt19937](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) to generate pseudo-random numbers:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> dis(min, max);
std::mt19937 gen(seed);
auto const randomnumber = dis(gen);
```

In your example you probably get an unexpected range because the character `'7'` (for instance) does not equal the number `7`. You might want to use `character[4]-'0'` as the maximum value.

When you enter `roll10` this gets translated into the last branch of your conditional, which means you have the numerical value for `'1'` plus the numerical value for `'0'` which is 48+49 = 97. So `x%97 + 1` allows for all values in [1..97] with an almost but not quite uniform distribution.

You probably are looking for something like this:

```
auto const max = static_cast<unsigned>(command[4]-'0')*10 + static_cast<unsigned>(command[5]-'0');
auto const randomnumber = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned>(1, max)(gen);
```