# Warning of conversion using srand

Tags: c++

I have `int r_number = 0;` as a global variable.

In the code below:

```
        srand(time(0));
        r_number = rand() % 1000 + 701;
```

It keep spamming this warnings:

```
1>: warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
```

Whats wrong in the conversion?

Comment: Don't use C's random library. Use C++ random library. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad/52869953 to see why

Comment: You can just add a cast to silence this warning: `srand((unsigned int)time(0));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VC++ Level 4 warning message means to say `time_t` is a larger type than `unsigned int` - probably 64 bits, so the value returned by `time()` need to be truncated to 32 bits to be passed to `srand()`. In this specific case it doesn't matter, but it may be an issue in other places (consider handling file size as `unsigned int` just to discover that the program crashes with files >= 4 GB in size).

To silence the warning use an explicit cast which tells the compiler you know what you're doing:

```
srand((unsigned)time(nullptr));
```

---

Having said that, using [`rand() % X` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad) because it is imprecise (among other things). The value returned by `rand()` is uniformly distributed between 0 and `RAND_MAX` but `RAND_MAX`+1 usually doesn't divide evenly by `X`, which would result in a biased distribution of `rand() % X`.

C++ comes with its own random number implementation which is in many ways better:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;                           // better than time()
    std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());                       // better than rand()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(701, 1701); // better than % 1000 + 701
    std::cout << dist(gen) << std::endl;
}
```