# Generate a random number depending on input in a defined interval

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate random numbers that deppend on input from user.

For example if user inputs `8`, I want to generate number from `5` to `7`,
`(8 - 3)` to `(8 - 1)`

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

    int x1;
    int x2;

    std::srand(time(0));

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "input : ";
        std::cin >> x1;

        x2 = std::rand() % (x1 - 1) + (x1 - 3);

        std::cout << "result : ";
        std::cout << x2 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the output is:

```
input : 8
result : 7
input : 8
result : 10
input : 8
result : 8
```

And I want `result` to be from `5` to `7`.

Comment: Using more modern methods, you can use a [uniform int distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). For your current solution, try to work out on pencil and paper how you'd use modulo and addition to constrain a random value to between `lowerBound` and `upperBound`. Hint: Right now your lower bound is `x1 - 3` and your upper bound is `2*x1 - 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Addressing your problem

With the expression:

```
x2 = std::rand() % (x1 - 1) + (x1 - 3);
```

Using your sample input, `rand % (x1 - 1)` will be `rand % 7`, this will render you values from `0` to `6`, adding `5` to that you'll have values from `5` to `11`.

If you are adamant in using `rand` you can use something like this:

```
x2 = rand() / (RAND_MAX / ((x1 - 1) - (x1 - 3) + 1) + 1) + x1 - 3;
```

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/WPnh1v)

The interval is corrected, and this is a less biased method of obtaining the random value than using the modulo, though this problem is never completely solvable when using `rand`, **it's a known drawback**, there are others, you can find several threads in the website which provide solid reasoning as to why you shouldn't use it, like, for instance:

[Why is the use of rand() considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52869166/6865932)

[Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/6865932)

You also have this more technical document kindly provided by [njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/780717/njuffa):

[Fast Random Integer Generation in an Interval](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10941.pdf)

Among many others.

---

#### Recommend method

C++ [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header provides better random number generation facilities, for example using [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) and the [Mersenne twister engine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    int x1;
    int x2;

    std::random_device rand_d; // random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 generator(rand_d()); // seed
    
    while (true)
    {
        std::cin >> x1;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> uniform_value(x1 - 3, x1 - 1); // setup the range
        x2 = uniform_value(generator); // generante the value
        std::cout << "result : " << x2 << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/xfKfGd)

Comment: Not my DV, but there might be objections to teaching the use of the modulo operator for restricting the output of a source of uniformly distributed random numbers to a specific integer range. This has well-known draw-backs. State of the art in this regard is represented by: Daniel Lemire, "Fast random integer generation in an interval." *ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation*, Vol. 29, No. 1, pp.1-12. ([preprint online](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10941))

Comment: @njuffa, yep, it can be that, I just went along with the OP method and a should have provided a more solid solution, added that, better late than never I guess, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: That business with `RAND_MAX` gains you nothing over a simple `rand() % 3`. Whatever you do, the outcome will necessarily be ever so slightly biased, because the number of possible values for `rand()` is not (usually) a multiple of 3.

Comment: @TonyK, granted, but the fault is the same, using `rand` when we can use far better methods.

Answer (score -3):

```
x2 = std::rand() % 3 + (x1 - 3);
```