# How can i check a variable type in a conditional statement in c++?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I am pretty new to c++ and im having an issue trying to get my program out of a loop when a string is entered for the variables cont, and answer. In python it is pretty easy to do simple checks but I am not sure what I should be doing in cpp. I tried doing a check using `if(typeid(answer)) == typeid(string))` but this doesnt work. I havent tried putting a check for
`'y'||'Y'||'n'||'N'` for cont but im assuming it would be something like that? just check for those 4 characters?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned seed;
    char cont = 'y';
    int answer = 0;
    seed = time(nullptr);
    srand(seed);
    rand() % 100 + 1;


    cout << "Lets play a math game!\n";

     while(cont == 'y')
    {
        int num1 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        int num2 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        cout << "What is the result of this addition? \n " << num1 << '\n' << "+" << num2 << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        if (typeid(answer)==typeid(string))
        {
            while(typeid(answer) == typeid(string))
            {
                cout << "Please enter an integer!" << endl;
                cin >> answer;
            }
        }
        else if (typeid(answer) == typeid(int)) {
            if (answer == (num1 + num2)) {
                cout << "You are correct, would you like to play again?" << endl;
                cin >> cont;
            } else {
                cout << "You were incorrect, would you like to try again? enter y/n" << endl;
                cin >> cont;
            }
        } else {
            answer = 0;
            cout << "You did not enter an integer!\n" << endl;
            cout << "Would you like to try again?" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int answer = 0;` is always an `int`, not a `string`. You can check if a variable is of some type in a `if` but thats not what you actually need

Comment: would something like if(inRange(0,200,answer)) work? What happens when a character is entered? do characters hold some integer value

Comment: Unrelated: You should read [Why is the use of rand() considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad)

Comment: In Python you read a string and convert it to a number, e.g. `int(input())`. In C++ this is done in one step with `int answer; cin >> answer;`. You have to check the state of `cin` to see if the read and conversion were successful. If it fails an error bit is set. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate. Or you can do the same as in Python. Read it into a string and convert it: `std::string answer; cin >> answer; std::stoi(answer);`

Answer (score 0):

> How can i check a variable type in a conditional statement in c++?

You do that already, though I'd do this instead:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int answer =0;
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<int,decltype(answer)>) {
        std::cout << "answer is indeed an int";
    }
}
```

However, this will always print the expected `answer is indeed an int`, because `answer` is an `int` not something else. If the user enters invalid input the variable `answer` declared as `int` will not turn into a `std::string`.

> would something like if(inRange(0,200,answer)) work?

No it would not. `std::cin >> answer;` either succeds to read a number, or it fails and then `0` is assigned to `answer`. You cannot decide if valid input was entered by looking at `answer` only.

To check if the user entered valid input you can check the state of the stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int answer =0;

    while(!(std::cin >> answer)){
        std::cout <<  "please enter a number\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    std::cout << answer;
}
```

Note that this accepts for example `42asdf` as valid input, because `std::cin >> answer` does read `42` before it encounters something that is not a number. For something more sophisticated you can read a `std::string` and parse that.

Comment: So, this works great, and I do not get stuck in any loops anymore, but for some reason I have to input answer twice. it does not react to the first answer, and it will prompt correct, incorrect, or please enter a number on the 2nd answer attempt. Im trying to copy paste my code into this comment but the formatting is completely off and confusing.
```
cin >> answer;

        while(!(cin >> answer)) {
            cout << "please enter a number\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        if (answer == (num1 + num2))
```

Comment: @JonathanTylerEcton-Rodriguez don't call `std::cin >> answer` twice. `while(!(std::cin >> answer))` does read `answer` and then checks the state of the stream

Comment: thanks, you were a great help, i learned a lot from this :)