# How to randomly pick element from an array with different probabilities in C++

Tags: c++, random, sampling

Suppose I have a `vector<Point> p` of some objects.

I can pick a uniformly random by simply `p[rand() % p.size()]`.

Now suppose I have another same-sized vector of doubles `vector <double> chances`.

I want to randomly sample from p with each element having a probability analogous to its value in `chances` (which may not be summing to 1.0). How can I achieve that in C++?

Comment: You can use `std::discrete_distribution` to obtain an integer distributed according to your vector of `chances`, and then use that integer as an index into your vector of points.

Comment: `rand() % someNumber` [is not a uniform distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for `std::discrete_distribution`. Forget about `rand()`.

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <vector>

struct Point {};

int main() {
    std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());

    std::vector<double> chances{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    // Initialize to same length.
    std::vector<Point> points(chances.size());
    // size_t is suitable for indexing.
    std::discrete_distribution<std::size_t> d{chances.begin(), chances.end()};

    auto sampled_value = points[d(gen)];
}
```

Conveniently for you, the weights do not have to sum to 1.

Comment: The algorithm normalises the weights with a pass over the vector of probabilities?

Comment: @Robinson Not sure I understand, `d` holds its own copy of probabilities/weights, `chances` are not modified. Whether they are normalized inside `d` is up to the implementation. Sampling is done from a prob. distribution given by the normalized weights.

Comment: No I mean I think it adds up all the probabilities to 1, and that's how it can sample the distribution as (1.0/sum, 2.0/sum, etc.).  Here sum is 6, so probabilities would be 1/6, 2/6 and 3/6, adding up to 1.  I was just wondering why the probabilities didn't have to sum you see.

Comment: @Robinson I see, I believe the lack of normalization requirement of the passed in weights is for pure convenience and to avoid re-normalization that the algorithm would have to do. It might also not be needed for the sampling algorithm as one can sometimes do away with cumulative sum only. But I am not sure which case is more stable w.r.t limited precision.