# How can I cout 1 or 2 in C++?

Tags: c++, cout

How can I cout 1 or 2 in C++? I would like to cout 1 or 2(randomly choose between them). What do I have to change to work well ?
This is not working, because it cout only the 1 number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ cout  << "1" || "2";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "1 or 2"? Do you want the program to choose randomly between them?

Comment: What do you mean by 1 or 2? Randomly?

Comment: Yes randomly choose between them.

Comment: `cout << "1 or 2";`?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: You will certainly want to  un-learn `or` / `||` meaning "randomly select one".  That is not what `||` does.

Comment: take a look at how to generate a random number, and how to do things according to that generated number.

Answer (score 0):

For 50/50 chance, you can just use

```
int randomNumber = (rand() % 2) + 1;
cout << randomNumber << endl;
```

rand() generates a random positive integer, %2 will make it randomly either 0 or 1, +1 will make it randomly either 1 or 2.

**EDIT**

As George pointed out in the comment, we need to add a seed to make it truly random, and there are better methods to do it. However, for someone just starting (which I guess the OP is), it is sufficient.

Comment: Please see [Why is the use of rand() considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad). Also, the number won't be random without seeding it.

Comment: @George thanks for your input. I agree it wont be truly random without seeding it. However, the question seems to have been asked by someone who is just starting out in programming. I didn't want to confuse them with a lot of concepts.