# `glm::linearRand(-1.0f, 1.0f)`, gives more negative numbers than positive. Why is that? `rand` seems ok

Tags: c++, random, glm-math

I am using `glm::linearRand(-1.0f, 1.0f)` to generate random floating point numbers between `-1` and `1`. Afterwards, I output the percentage of numbers that are positive (`0.0f` or above).

```cpp
std::srand(time(0)); // Give glm a new seed

uint32_t samples = 1000000000;
uint32_t positive = 0;
uint32_t negative = 0;

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
    float rand = glm::linearRand(-1.0f, 1.0f);

    if (rand >= 0.0f) {
        positive++;
    } else {
        negative++;
    }
}

std::cout << "positive %: " << std::setprecision(6) << ((float)positive / samples) * 100 << std::endl;
```

The percentage of positive numbers always ends up around `49.6%`, no matter how often I run the program (with different seeds!). If I understand floating point numbers correctly, there are equally many between `-1.0f` and `0.0f` as there are between `0.0f` and `1.0f`.

So why does this program always generate more negative numbers than positive numbers?

Note [this test code](https://godbolt.org/z/9jq1bG35j) provided by `Bob__` (result of comments exchange between him, `IkarusDeveloper` and `Marek R`).
This proves that `rand` is not problem this time, but there is some problem with floats rounding inside of `glm::linearRand`.

Comment: which system/compiler? If MSVC then MSVC has very old `rand` which RAND_MAX has only 16 bits.

Comment: Unrelated, just to let you know that there is also a prefix increment operator

Comment: Is it always the exactly the same positive value (if you don't round it)?  Does positive + negative = 1000000000.  What if you decrease/increase from 1000000000?

Comment: [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YqdYKc3o9)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, so I voted to reopen. This is more like `rand` has poor quality.

Comment: [This is best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52870307/1387438) I've found so far about `rand`, but it doesn't explain why there are more negative numbers in this case.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/FsCaJhXjP0 it looks like it depends on the implementation of `std::rand`, in the sample on onlinegdb it push out 50.0008% positive numbers, you may copy my sample and check if your computer push out the same numbers that you found with your sample.

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper my live demo uses `glm` library so it is exact same as OP code. Your example uses `rand()` in a bit different way. In fact you are using `double` in many places, so different rounding issue pops up. This is a good clue what actual problem is.

Comment: @MarekR I changed the code made sure to only use floats and the result remains different. My example does not use glm but uses its own implementation, I don't think that's what makes the difference. I think it is more likely that the difference is caused by different implementations of `std::rand` in the C-runtime library.
https://onlinegdb.com/hGCxCFFe7

Comment: so i tested on your online compiler and the result is really strange. https://godbolt.org/z/1f1cT8z7E
i just copied glm::getLinearRand implementation on testRand and it push out differently

Comment: I voted for reopen, because the culprit [doesn't seem](https://godbolt.org/z/9jq1bG35j) to be `rand`, this time, but `glm::linearRand`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a **bug** in GLM.  While the usual admonition about using `%` with `rand` is that the range doesn’t evenly divide `RAND_MAX`, this code opts for the [more straightforward approach](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/6ad79aae3eb5bf809c30bf1168171e9e55857e45/glm/gtc/random.inl#L25) of reducing `rand()` modulo `UINT8_MAX`, so that 255 is **never** produced.  Every random value is ultimately derived from combining several such bytes, so 127/255=49.8% of the values will be in the upper half (here, positive).