# How much can I change code to keep rand() giving same output for given seed?

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

I'm implementing an algorithm. Because calculations takes time, and I need to repeat them multiple times, I'm saving to output file seed values as well. The idea was that I could repeat same instance of a program if I'll need to get more info about what was happening (like additional values, some percentage, anything that will not mess in the algorithm itself).

Unfortunately, even though I thought everything worked as intended, about 20% of the seeded instances gave different values in at least one of the outputted values.

My question is - **what type of changes in the code affects how `srand() / rand()` works in C++?** **Each class is compiled separately and all are linked together at the end.** Can I implement functions and everything will be fine? Does it break only when I change the size of any class in the program by adding/removing class fields? Is it connected with heap/stack allocation?

Until now, I thought that if I seed `srand()` I will have same order of `rand()` values no matter what (eg. for `srand(123)` I'll always get first `rand() == 5`, second `rand() == 8` etc.). And I can break it only when I'll put more `rand()` calls in between.

I hope you could find where I'm thinking wrong, or you could link something that will help me.

Cheers
mrozo

Comment: Your thought of `srand` and `rand` are correct, that's how they should work. Do you have a [mre] of the problematic code you can show us?

Comment: On another note, since the C++11 standard (published over ten years ago, and supported by all major compilers) there's a much better [pseudo-random generation library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). It also supports setting seeds and should be predictable from the seed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Unfortunately, I don't think that I could be able to make minimal reproducible example from that. But maybe I found another problem, according to the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) `srand` is not guaranteed to be thread safe. I'm not using threads in the program itself, but I'm using [GNU parralel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to run same program multiple times on many threads.

Comment: Also, from your second comment I understand that `srand` should be avoided. In my algorithm I'm calling `rand` thousands of times, so if 46/60 program executions for different topologies (network optimization problem) gives excactly the same results, where most of the outputs are more complicated than 0/1 (that could be reproduced by luck), then maybe there is accually a problem with `rand` not being always predictable.

Comment: Not just `srand`, but `rand` should be avoided in general in C++ programs nowadays.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding about `srand` is correct: seeding with a specific value should be enough to generate a reproducible sequence of random numbers. You should debug your application to discover why it behaves in a non-reproducible way.

One reason for such behavior is a race condition on the hidden RNG state. Quoting from the [C++ `rand` wiki](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand):

> It is implementation-defined whether `rand()` is thread-safe.
>
> ...
>
> It is recommended to use C++11's random number generation facilities to replace `rand()`.

Comment: How should I understand *thread-safe*? Of course it refers to obvious - when you implement multiple threads in the single program. But if I execute multiple times a compiled program on multiple threads simultaneously (I'm using [GNU parralel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to do so), could it be also a threat for *thread-safe* that wiki refers to?

Comment: I don't know any details about GNU parallel. I think yes, it should have problems with non-thread-safe code. You can check this using a simple test program, or possibly ask a dedicated question on that.

Comment: @mrozo -- even if `rand()` is thread-safe, calling it from multiple threads will not produce consistent results, because the sequence of the calls will vary. If that's what your code is doing, getting reproducible sequences requires a separate random number generator for each thread. `rand()` isn't equipped for that.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks a lot, I'll look for different random number generator that will work for those kind of calls.