# random number returning same pattern

Tags: c++

I have a function which is supposed to generate a random number depending of the size of a vector. But each time I execute my program, the patterns are the same `1->1->1->0` but my array can contains `0-4` value.

```cpp
std::pair<int, int> Maze::getDirection(int x, int y)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> location;

    if (m_maze[x + 1][y] == '*')
        location.emplace_back(std::make_pair(x + 1, y));

    if (m_maze[x - 1][y] == '*')
        location.emplace_back(std::make_pair(x - 1, y));

    if (m_maze[x][y + 1] == '*')
        location.emplace_back(std::make_pair(x, y + 1));

    if (m_maze[x][y - 1] == '*')
        location.emplace_back(std::make_pair(x, y - 1));

    std::cout << "Random number: " << std::rand() % location.size() << "\n" << "Size of vector: " << location.size() << std::endl;
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    return location.at(std::rand() % location.size());
}
```

Comment: `std::srand(std::time(nullptr));` does **not** belong in a repeatedly called function. It should be called **once**, preferably near the beginning of `main`. And since this is C++, you should ideally be using the offerings of [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) anyway.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate your observation. The shown code is not plausibly matching it.

Comment: If none of the positions contains a `*` then `std::rand() % location.size()` becomes a division by zero.

Comment: [Why is the use of rand() considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad)

Answer (score 1):

`std::srand(std::time(nullptr));` reseeds the `rand()` PRNG every time you call the function. If you call it many times during one second, it'll get the same seed and restart the number cycle for that seed.

You should only call `std::srand()` once during the whole program run. There are also better tools than `rand()` and `%` to get random numbers. Since C++11, you can use one of the PRNG:s in [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), like `std::mt19937` combined with a [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to get numbers in the range you want - and it will not be biased like using `%` is for most cases.

Example:

```cpp
#include <random>

// A seeded PRNG from the standard library since C++11. Use the same generator
// everywhere in your program. If your program is multithreaded, make it `thread_local`:
std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};

std::pair<int, int> Maze::getDirection(int x, int y) {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> location;

    // note: make_pair is not needed when using emplace_back to create a pair:
    if (m_maze[x + 1][y] == '*') location.emplace_back(x + 1, y);
    if (m_maze[x - 1][y] == '*') location.emplace_back(x - 1, y);
    if (m_maze[x][y + 1] == '*') location.emplace_back(x, y + 1);
    if (m_maze[x][y - 1] == '*') location.emplace_back(x, y - 1);
    
    if(location.empty()) return {-1, -1}; // dead end

    // A distribution to scale the PRNG:s random numbers
    // from 0 to location.size() - 1
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> dist(0, location.size() - 1);

    auto random_number = dist(gen); // generate the number

    std::cout << "Random number: " << random_number << '\n'
              << "Size of vector: " << location.size() << '\n';

    return location[random_number];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**rand** function can follow the same pattern against the number of iterations so what it cannot randomized as well. Use **srand** to make them random output and no pattern following algorithm.

Comment: OP _is_ using `srand`