# What is the difference between using the '*' operator vs the '%' operator when using the rand() function in C++?

Tags: c++, random, integer, double, modulo

Below I am going to show two different versions of rand() implementations.

First, the modulo operator (%):

```
int r = rand() % 10;
```

Now, I know that this statement produces a random integer between 0-9.

Second, the multiplication operator(*):

```
double r = rand() * 101.0 / 100.0;
```

This is the one I am confused about. I have seen this implementation once before but I cannot find a good explanation of what the 'rules' are here. What are the bounds/restrictions? What is the purpose of the division instead of just typing:

```
double r = rand() * 1.0;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52869166/430766 It is highly related but I don't think a dupe.

Comment: There is nothing special about using `*` and `%` "when using the rand() function". So I'm not sure if your question is "what does `rand()` actually return" or "what do the modulo and multiplication operators actually do"

Comment: To state the obvious: One difference between `rand() * 101.0 / 100.0` and `rand() * 1.0` is that `101.0 / 100.0` is `1.01`, not `1.0`.

Comment: This might be even more related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/430766 It explains in detail why the `rand() %` idiom is really bad.

Comment: The second code line doesn't make any sense whatsoever. Are you sure that uses the ```rand()``` from the standard C library, not some custom ```rand()```? The division that you normally see is something like ```(double) rand() / RAND_MAX``` to get a floating point number between 0 and 1.

Comment: @bitmask -- `rand() % 10` is pretty good; slightly biased, but not enough to matter in beginner programs. For beginners struggling to get code to work, fixing the bias is a major distraction.

Comment: @PeteBecker This might be a philosophical dispute, but why learn a technique that is broken, when a stable alternative is available? Especially since understanding why the modulo is bad teaches you a number of interesting things. Furthermore `rand` itself is bad. No useful guarantees whatsoever.

Comment: @bitmask -- it's not broken. For many things it works just fine. Unfortunately, programmers often fall into the "if it's not perfect it's useless" fallacy.

Comment: In C++, [rand() is considered harmful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no different implementations for `rand()` function.
The difference in these two cases is the **mathematical operation** you do with the value returned by `rand()` function.

In the first case you just take the number returned by `rand()` and divide it to 10 using modulo operator (so getting a number between 0 to 9). And in the second case you just multiplying it by 101 (or 1).

For example `rand()` has returned number 123.
case first: 123 % 10 gives you 3 (the reminder of the normal division).
case second: you just multiply 123 by 101 which is 12423.

Checkout *[this](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/).*