# I want to use my own random function with std::shuffle, but it is not working

Tags: c++, testing

I get an error when I use myRand::RandInt instead of something like default_random_engine. But I don't understand how am I supposed to implement the random_engine function. What I've done works well with std::random_shuffle, but I understand that this function was deprecated, and std::shuffle is preferred.

I am trying to get this to work:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::shuffle (v.begin(), v.end(), myRand::RandInt);
  
    return 0;
}
```

I've defined a namespace to implement the functions:

```
namespace myRand {
    bool simulatingRandom = false;
    std::vector<int> secuenciaPseudoRandom = {1,0,1,0};
    long unsigned int index = 0;
    
    int Rand() {
        //check
        if (index > secuenciaPseudoRandom.size() - 1 ) {
            index = 0;
            std::cout << "Warning: myRand resetting secuence" << std::endl;
        };
        
        if (simulatingRandom) {
            //std::cout << "myRand returning " << secuenciaPseudoRandom[i] << std::endl;
            return secuenciaPseudoRandom[index++];
        }
        else {
            return rand();
        }
    }

    // works as rand() % i in the case of simulatingRandom == false
    int RandInt(int i) {

        return Rand() %i;
    }
}
```

Basically I want to be able to change between simulating random and true random easily for testing purposes. So that in my main code I can do the testing with simulatingRandom set to true and then change it to false. Maybe there is a better way to do testing of functions that involves random. If so, I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: In cppreference says that std::shuffle takes URBG as its 3rd parameter. but I cannot find any information about what that is or how to implement it.

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle under "Type requirements": "`std::remove_reference_t<URBG>` must meet the requirements of [UniformRandomBitGenerator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UniformRandomBitGenerator)."

Comment: By the way the random number generators in the standard library are simulating random.For a truly random number you need a hardware device. In fact if you start with the same seed you can replicate the 'random' sequence as often as you want by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the last argument to [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) must meet the requirements of [`UniformRandomBitGenerator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UniformRandomBitGenerator). The generator should be an object not a function. For example a minimal implementation would be:

```
struct RandInt
{
    using result_type = int;

    static constexpr result_type min()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    static constexpr result_type max()
    {
        return RAND_MAX;
    }

    result_type operator()()
    {
        return Rand();
    }
};
```

You can then call it as:

```
std::shuffle (v.begin(), v.end(), myRand::RandInt());
```

Note that you'l need to adjust the values of `min` and `max` if you set your `simulatingRandom` value to `true` to match the expected values. If they don't match the true values `std::shuffle` probably wont be as random as it should be.

Have to finish with the usual reminder not to use `rand` in modern code: [Why is the use of rand() considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad) especially without calling `srand` first. The use of `rand` is the main reason `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated.