# What is the most rng-efficient uniform random integer algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, random, biginteger, optimal

This is not a duplicate of [#11766794 “What is the optimal algorithm for generating an unbiased random integer within a range?”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11766794/1874170). Both its top-upvoted answer and its Accepted answer have to do with **floating-point extrapolation**, which will not even yield perfectly uniform integers. That question is asking after ways to quickly get good *approximations* of a uniform random integer given a serviceably uniform floating-point `rand()` value; I am asking this question in the context of a *perfectly* uniform random integer algorithm given a true [random bit generator](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35007/8287) (deterministic or otherwise; the question applies equally either way).

I am asking, specifically, about theoretical optimality in terms only of **efficiency w/r/t random bits used**: *given* a random bit stream, what is the algorithm which consumes the *fewest* number of bits from it in the process of generating a perfectly uniform random integer within a given range?

For instance, [CPython 3.9.0's `random.randbelow`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0/Lib/random.py#L237-L247) has at least one trivial inefficiency—it wastes a random bit when called over any power of 2 (including the trivial range):

```py
def randbelow(n):
    "Return a random int in the range [0,n).  Returns 0 if n==0."
    if not n:
        return 0
    k = n.bit_length()  # don't use (n-1) here because n can be 1
    r = getrandbits(k)  # 0 <= r < 2**k
    while r >= n:
        r = getrandbits(k)
    return r
```

While this is easily enough patched by replacing "`not n`" with "`n <= 1`" and "`n.bit_length()`" with "`(n-1).bit_length()`", a little analysis shows it leaves even more to be desired:

Say one is generating an integer over the range `[0, 4097)`: *half* of all the calls to `getrandbits(13)` will overshoot the value: if the first bit and, *say*, the second bit are high, it will consume 11 *more* bits anyway, and discard them when it seemingly didn't need to. So it would seem that this algorithm is obviously nonoptimal.

The best I could come with in an hour this evening was the following algorithm:

```py
def randbelow(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 0
    k = (n - 1).bit_length() # this is POPCNT for bignums
    while True:
        r = 0
        for i in reversed(range(k)):
            r |= getrandbits(1) << i
            if r >= n:
                break
        else:
            return r
```

However, I am no mathematician, and just because I fixed the inefficiencies *that I could immediately see* doesn't give me any confidence that I have just instantly stumbled in an afternoon on the most efficient possible uniform integer selection algorithm.

Say, for instance, the bits are being purchased from a quantum or atmospheric RNG service; or as part of a multi-party protocol in which every individual bit generation takes several round-trips; or on [an embedded device without any hardware RNG support](https://forum.arduino.cc/search?q=uno%20rng)… *whatever the case may be*, I'm only asking the direct question: what algorithm for generating (perfectly) uniformly random integers from a true random bit stream is the most efficient **with respect to random bits consumed**? (Or, if not known with certainty, what *is* the best current candidate?)

(I have used Python in these examples because it's what I am working in primarily this season, but the question is by no means specific to any language, except inasfaras the *algorithm itself* must generalize to numbers above 2<sup>64</sup>.)

Comment: [An optimal algorithm for bounded random integers](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/39143)

Comment: Arithmetic coding (rob's link is a rediscovery without attribution). The precision requirement grows without bound unless you're willing to take a little waste, however.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62902524/815724) in the first question you linked to, or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046918/.  In fact, I have given answers to [questions similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user:815724%20Knuth%20yao).

Comment: @PeterO. Thanks for the tip! I would not have expected to find such a gem of an answer buried _so far down_ the ranking of #11766794. Further, your answer to #6046918 addresses my question directly, and I'm peeved that I didn't find it while drafting this. I'll mark this question as a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 1):

The Python below implements [arithmetic coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) in exact arithmetic. This becomes very expensive computationally but achieves entropy + O(1) bits in expectation, which is basically optimal.

```
from fractions import Fraction
from math import floor, log2
import random


meter = 0


def metered_random_bits():
    global meter
    while True:
        yield bool(random.randrange(2))
        meter += 1


class ArithmeticDecoder:
    def __init__(self, bits):
        self._low = Fraction(0)
        self._width = Fraction(1)
        self._bits = bits

    def randrange(self, n):
        self._low *= n
        self._width *= n
        while True:
            f = floor(self._low)
            if self._low + self._width <= f + 1:
                self._low -= f
                return f
            self._width /= 2
            if next(self._bits):
                self._low += self._width


import collections

if __name__ == "__main__":
    k = 3000
    n = 7
    decoder = ArithmeticDecoder(metered_random_bits())
    print(collections.Counter(decoder.randrange(n) for i in range(k)))
    print("used", meter, "bits")
    print("entropy", k * log2(n), "bits")
```

Comment: Obviously, if you're able to "batch up" the draws, you can get arbitrarily close to 100% efficiency… but what about in expectation for **single-draw, without the ability to preserve state between draws**? (This was the intent behind my original question—I take the blame for not properly expressing it, as I had forgotten about arithmetic coding.)

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I think that the Fast Dice Roller described in Peter's linked answer is optimal.