# What's the best way of generating a random number in a discontinuous range?

Tags: c, algorithm

Is there a better way than:

```
#define BOUND 7

int r;
int e = 1;

r = rand() % BOUND;

while (r == e){

    r = rand() % BOUND;
}
```

for generating numbers in a range except for a value `e`?

Comment: do you need values to be equally distributed?

Comment: BTW, I don't understand what your code is supposed to do

Comment: Make an array of  *possible* values and then randomly pick from it.

Comment: @OznOg Looks like it keeps re rolling the value of `r` while it's equivalent to `e`.

Comment: @OznOg Yes I do need equal distribution.

Comment: @Nae if BOUND is relative prime to maximum possible generated number then it is not equally distributed.

Comment: generate in range BOUND-1 and add 1 if it is >= e

Comment: @Sopel How is it better than OPs solution?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Because it doesn't have a loop

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Hm, let's assume for the sake of the algorithm `BOUND` is never relative prime.

Comment: Partial dupe : [Generating a uniform distribution of INTEGERS in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641629/generating-a-uniform-distribution-of-integers-in-c).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're asking for is generating a random number in the range `[0, BOUND)` excluding the value `e`

The [algorithm explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182699/random-integer-in-a-certain-range-excluding-one-number) seems to be the best way to do it without using a loop.

Here is the C code:

```
#define BOUND 7

int r;
int e = 1;

r = rand() % (BOUND-1);

if (r >= e){
    r = r+1;
}
```

So, you basically generate a value in the range `[0, BOUND-1)`, and if the value is greater than or equal to the excluded value `e`, you increment the random number by one.

**Keep in mind** that using `rand` with `%` does not guarantee a strict uniform distribution across the generated numbers. For more info, [check out this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c).

Answer (score 5):

To generate a pseudo-random number in a range with a uniform distribution among values, it is much more reliable to use the magnitude of the value returned by `rand()` rather than its remainder for the division `rand() % BOUND`:

```
int r = (long long)rand() * BOUND / (RAND_MAX + 1LL);
```

`rand()` returns a value between `0` and `RAND_MAX` included: the division must use `RAND_MAX + 1LL` so the result is in range `0` included .. `BOUND` excluded (as commented by chux).

If you want to exclude a given value, reduce the range by one and adjust the result:

```
#define BOUND 7

int r = (long long)rand() * (BOUND - 1) / (RAND_MAX + 1LL);
if (r >= 1) { // shift values 1..5 to 2..6
    r += 1;
}
```

Here is a more general version:

```
// select a random value from a set
int set[] = { 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int r = set[(long long)rand() * (sizeof(set) / sizeof(*set)) / (RAND_MAX + 1LL)];
```

Comment: `int r = (long long)rand() * BOUND / RAND_MAX;`  causes an unneeded distribution bias and can leave `r` with the value of `BOUND`.  This could be fixed with `int r = (long long)rand() * BOUND / (RAND_MAX + 1LL);`.

Comment: @chux: absolutely! I should have been more careful.

Comment: Right, I seem to have messed that up. Sorry. @chqrlie