# How can I generate random probability values using C programming language?

Tags: c, random

If I do `rand()/RAND_MAX`, will it give me a random probability value?

If I do so, is it going to be that 50% (on average) of the values will be more than 0.5?

Comment: Make it `rand() / (double)RAND_MAX` otherwise it's an integer division which will be almost always `0`.

Comment: just use `1.*rand()/RAND_MAX` - since rand() can return 0 and RAND_MAX both this can return a value from 0.0 to 1.0 inclusive

Comment: It's random so your results will vary, but I got `Number less than 0.5    = 50000517` `Number greater than 0.5 = 49999483` https://onlinegdb.com/BJd-joSEd

Comment: rand() is known to be utterly bad pseudo-random number generator, so YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Never use `rand()` for any purpose, ever.

`random()` is likely suitable for your needs. (`#include <stdlib.h>`) It generates a uniform distribution in the range 0..2<sup>31</sup>-1. `random() / (double)((1L << 31) - 1)` should get you close to a uniform distribution between `0.0` and `1.0`.

You can use `srandomdev()` to seed it in order to get a different sequence every time.

Here is a histogram of one billion values returned by `random()` in 256 bins over the range 0..2<sup>31</sup>-1:

[image: uniform]

If you look closely, you can see the expected tiny variations from uniform along the top of the histogram.

Comment: I do not see any mention of a distribution in my man pages, nor in the POSIX manual. Can you elaborate on the function distribution?

Comment: It should say that explicitly, but it is both expected for any such random number generator, as well as implicit in the generation of pseudo-random numbers using these overflow/modulo arithmetic approaches. All possible values in the range are equally accessible to the sequence.

Comment: So the sequence is uniformly distributed?

Comment: @user14063792468 the picture shows **one billion** values, I would consider it uniform enough, and can produce only 2^31 distinct values but in any case would be much better than `rand()` which is guaranteed to only produce 2^15 distinct values.

Comment: @user14063792468 See histogram.

Comment: @MarkAdler Sure, looks uniform. BTW, thanks for sparing a time to produce one.

Comment: @MarkAdler Is it `FreeBSD` or `Linux`? I`m asking because if the histogram is a Linux one, I bet on it to get some uniform distribution.

Comment: macOS. Just as uniform on Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD.

Comment: note that those bin counts (should be) Poisson distributed with mean=1e9/256.  given that they are around 600 pixels high, the expected variance would around 2 pixels (i.e. `round(qpois(c(1,255)/256, mu) / mu*600)` in R), which looks right to me.

Comment: Since the mean is so large, the Poisson distribution is very closely approximated by a Gaussian distribution whose mean and variance is equal to the mean of the Poisson. Then if I compute the standard deviation of the 256 bins, I should get something close to the square root of the mean, which is 1976. Indeed, when I compute the standard deviation of the bins in the histogram above, I get 2029.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes the `rand() / (double)RAND_MAX` will give you a random value.
2. No, `rand()` have no mention of a uniform(or any other) distribution. There is no guarantee that "is it going to be that 50% (on average)".

Have a uniform distribution in `C` is a different question. You may be interested in [Generating a uniform distribution of INTEGERS in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11641629/8339821)
 SO topic.

Comment: note that it's generally a requirement that (P)RNGs be uniformly distributed.  i.e. each bit be true with probability 0.5 and all independent of each other.  exceptions tend to be called out, for example with [xoshiro256+](https://prng.di.unimi.it/) this isn't true for the low order bits, but these bits are discarded when used as it's been designed so worth it for the performance win

Comment: @SamMason Honestly, really, I do not knew it.